# Load same html for all pages

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have an app shell in my `index.html` file. I want to load this app shell for all URLs except for those starting with `/api/` (AJAX calls). How do I set my configuration to achieve this?

`service-worker.js:`

```
(function() {

'use strict';

var filesToCache = [
    '.',
    'index.html',
    'pwa-stylesheets/css/styles-new.css'
];

var staticCacheName = 'cache-v3';

self.addEventListener( 'install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(staticCacheName)
        .then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
        }).then( function() {
            self.skipWaiting();
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener( 'fetch', function(event) {
    var url = event.request.url;
    if( url.indexOf( "http://localhost:8080" ) > -1 
        && url.indexOf( "http://localhost:8080/api/" ) == -1
        && url.indexOf( "http://localhost:8080/pwa-" ) == -1 ) {
        // event.request.url = "http://localhost:8080/"; // not allowed
        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request).then( function( response ) {
                if( response ) {
                    console.log( 'Found ', url, ' in cache' );
                    return response;
                }
                console.log( 'Network request for ', url );
                return fetch( event.request ).then( function( response ) {
                    if( ! response.ok ) {
                        console.log( "Network request failed." );
                        return null;
                    }
                    return caches.open( staticCacheName ).then( function(cache) {
                        cache.put(event.request.url, response.clone());
                        return response;
                    });
                });
            })
        );
    } 
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {

    var cacheWhitelist = [staticCacheName];

    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
                    if( cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1 ) {
                        return caches.delete(cacheName);
                    }
                })
            );
        })
    );
});

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

what you will want to do is configure your fetch event handler to catch or filter the api calls. When you see a request for a url containing /api/ you will want to hit the network with a fetch call. Use a regular expression to check the request URL to apply the cache strategy you want for your API or any other url for that matter.

Comment: Yeah, I can add a filter for all api requests, not a problem. But, cache api has only get method which operates on event.request object. And somehow I have to map /, /link1, /link2 to same index.html file.

Comment: Then you need to catch those request URLs and create your own response object in the server worker. This is similar to having a fallback response logic.
Check out the generic fallback strategy - https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#generic-fallback
You would need to modify it a little for your needs.